# Is it a good practice to setNeedsLayout/setNeedsDisplay from CALayer's methods?

Tags: cocoa, core-animation

My layer has a couple of dynamic properties that affect layout and/or display of the layer itself. Is it okay if I send `setNeedsLayout`/`setNeedsDisplay` from the setters of the properties or the caller of the setter is responsible for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's fine to call setNeedsLayout or setNeedsDisplay from the setters inside your UIView subclass.  They return immediately and call layoutSubviews only once in the next drawing cycle.

Comment: I'm talking about CALayer and subclasses.